# Is there any way to track quests?

Tags: west-of-loathing

The biggest issue I have with West of Loathing is that unlike in Kingdom of Loathing, there doesn't seem to be a way to track active quests. So I know there are people who want specific things of me, but often by the time I get the thing they want, I forget who wants it and where they are. I suspect this will get worse as I do normal people things in between playing the game and all of the stuff falls out of my head.

Is there any way to track quest-like things? Or do I have to rely on my sketchy memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some poking about, I discovered that talking to your pardner gives you a few options. One of them is that you can ask them "What do you think we should do next", which seems to give you a hint on what you can do to progress the story. The other important one is "Am I forgetting about anything", and you can get some hints on stuff you should do but haven't yet (like tasks people you've encountered have given you, stuff like that).

So there's not a big tracking system (at least not that I've discovered) like other RPG style games may have, but at least this way you have a way to jog your memory, if you're like me and tend to forget things a lot.

Comment: There are also things to do that aren't part of the pardner's dialogue, like solving the El Vibrato puzzles and unlocking the Alexandria ranch vault. And as you go through the world and come across clues of the necromancer's rituals, you will populate the "Necromancer's Journal" that collects the clues found so far.